# How can I convert month 6 to June? Is it possible?

Tags: python, calendar

Question: How can I convert month 6 to June? Is it possible?

```
input:
import calendar
y= int(input('Input the year: '))
m=int(input('Input the month: '))
print("Here's the calendar {},{}".format(m,y))
output:
Input the year: 2021
Input the month: 6
Here's the calendar 6,2021
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a dictionary mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
import calendar
y= int(input('Input the year: '))
m=int(input('Input the month: '))
months = {
    1: 'January', 
    2: 'February',
    3: 'March',
    4: 'April',
    5: 'May',
    6: 'June',
    7: 'July',
    8: 'August',
    9: 'September',
    10: 'October',
    11: 'November',
    12: 'December'
}
print("Here's the calendar {},{}".format(months[m],y))
```

Comment: Is this a dictionary?   months = {
    1: 'January', 
    2: 'February',
    3: 'March',
    4: 'April',
    5: 'May',
    6: 'June',
    7: 'July',
    8: 'August',
    9: 'September',
    10: 'October',
    11: 'November',
    12: 'December'
}

Comment: @PhongDiep Yes, that is a simple dictionary. I did it this way to show you the simplest way. (It was done by hand, and there are shorter ways, but for learning, it is the best).

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar
import datetime
y= int(input('Input the year: '))
m=int(input('Input the month: '))
monthObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(m),"%m")
monthName = monthObject.strftime("%B")
print("Here's the calendar {},{}".format(monthName,y))
```

this is the answer
"%B" for full month names and "%b" for abbreviated month name
ex.

```
monthName = monthObject.strftime("%b")
```

Answer (score 0):

With `calendar` and `enumerate`, we can generate the mapping:

```
import calendar

mapping = dict(enumerate(calendar.month_name))
```

which gives

```
>>> mapping
{0: "", 1: "January", 2: "February", 3: "March", 4: "April", 5: "May", 6: "June",
 7: "July", 8: "August", 9: "September", 10: "October", 11: "November", 12: "December"}
```

(convenient that it gives empty string for the 0th entry, so we can index naturally, i.e., 6 for June, not 5).

Then you can use as:

```
>>> inp = 6
>>> month_name = mapping[inp]
>>> month_name
"June"
```